# ¿Cómo puedo descargar la imagen CAPTCHA de una página Web?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para la pagina Web de mi escuela para ver las calificaciones y detalles escolares, he estado haciendo una búsqueda de como podría hacer el inicio de sesión desde Android y me encontré con `JSOUP`, hasta aquí todo va bien el problema que tengo ahora es que la página Web tiene captcha y necesito descargarla para visualizarla en un `ImageView`.

[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619161/getting-captcha-image-using-jsoup) muestra como puedo hacer eso, solo que cuando lo implemento me muestra otra imagen diferente a la que debería de mostrar.

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .timeout(300000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0")
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();

            //Get cookies
            cookies = response.cookies();

            String imgSrc = field.attr("src");
            Log.d("IMAGESRC", url + imgSrc);
            imgSrc = url + imgSrc;
            // Download image from URL
            InputStream input = new URL(imgSrc).openStream();
            // Decode Bitmap
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

Quisiera poder obtener el CAPTCHA y hacer un login con ello desde Android

[Página de la escuela](https://www.saes.upiicsa.ipn.mx/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A pesar de que esa imagen sea diferente, se valida correctamente o no?

Comment: Cada petición que hagas para obtener la imagen, se genera otro captcha, debes mirar de como capturarlo de una sola petición

Answer (score 4):

Normalmente, los captchas se persisten por sesión de usuario (cache, session, cokies,etc), es decir cada vez que realizas un request (una solicitud) la imagen será una nueva por solicitud, y sin embargo se validará perfectamente. El descargar la misma imagen que ves de la web en ese momento lo único que hará es generar error al validar ya que no se trata de la misma imagen generada por esta nueva solicitud.

Te recomiendo revisar las fuentes de algún captcha, para que entiendas el ciclo por el que pasa.